# How to push_back a unique_ptr in the vector of a derived class

Tags: c++11, inheritance, smart-pointers

I have an assignment to replicate the linux shell commands (ls, mkdir, etc) so I'm using a general tree structure. Basically, the directory class has a vector of pointers to either the base class (file) or another derived class (directory). Whenever I try to push_back a unique pointer to a new directory, I get the following error.

```
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function 
for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<FileData*>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<Directory,
std::default_delete<Directory> >)’
 { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my code

```cpp
#include "FileData.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <memory>

class Directory : public FileData
{
    private:
        Directory * parent;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FileData*>> files;
        void eraseString(std::string & mainString, 
                const std::string & stringToErase);
        int amountOfChar(const std::string & check);
    public:
        Directory();
        Directory(Directory * par);
        ~Directory();
        Directory(const Directory & x);
        void listComputerFiles(std::string input);
        void changeDirectory(std::string input);
        void makeDirectory(std::string input);
        void removeDirectory(std::string input);
        void makeFile(std::string input);
        void removeFile(std::string input);
        void printCurrentDirectory();
};

class FileData
{
    friend class Directory;
    protected:
        std::string name;
        std::string restrictions;
        std::string timestamp;
        std::string owner;
        std::string group;
        int dataSize;
        int numberOfItems;
    public:
        FileData();
        FileData(std::string nameOfFile, std::string restrict, std::string time, 
            std::string own, int size, int itemNumber);
        virtual ~FileData();
};
```

And here is where the error happens

```cpp
files.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Directory>(new Directory(*this)));
```

I tried many different combinations from other users having similars issues but to no avail including using a shared_ptr. As you can probably tell, I have no experience working with smart pointers, but felt like it was helpful to use them in this case due to having nested directories to clean up felt daunting.

Answer (score 0):

`unique_ptr<T>` is wrapper for `T*` raw pointer.

When you write `unique_ptr<FileData*>`, it makes `FileData**` as inner pointer. It is not what you want.

Just write:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FileData>> files;
```

---

When you use *emplace* family functions you should pass arguments which will be used to construct `unique_ptr` instance:

```
files.emplace_back( new Directory(*this) );
```

or

```
files.emplace_back( new Directory() );
```

---

The fully constructed object of `unique_ptr` is required by `push_back` method:

```
files.push_back(std::make_unique<Directory>(new Directory(*this)));
```

Comment: I get a new error now, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Error at compilation time, is not the same what runtime error. So now your code compiles, fine. When you get runtime error , the best way to find out why you get it, is to use debugger. Or you can ask another question, with MCVE.

Comment: I used the debugger and it just goes to my Directory class and then my FileData class, and then the error happens. Perhaps something to do with the constructors?